# Error Import Binding in Biztalk Administration Console

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I created a Project that Binds a view in the database. I created schema, map and Orchestration and deployed the project.I wanted to import the Binding to the project in the BizTalk Administration console.

But it is showing me an error like,

### TITLE: Import Bindings

Failed to update binding information. (mscorlib)

Can anybody tell me what is the issue. I even checked the Generate Unique Schema Types in the Consumer Adapter Service window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved. Because the Binding file had the same send port name which was already existing. The change in the Binding file Send port name helped to resolve the issue.